# Save credentials via WebView to Android device

Tags: android, webview

I'm making a simple **Android app** that uses a **WebView** to load my website. Everything seems to be working fine except that the user has to login every time the app opens up.

I'm fairly new to Android - what would be the best way to handle a situation as this? I'd like to save the credentials from the **WebView** to the device and if the user already logged in - I would like the home page of the app to open up.

I used **SharedPreferences** but was told it is unsafe. What would be the best alternative?

Comment: If you don't want save data in SharedPreferences then use Database. Android use SQLITE database.

Comment: I already have a database - it's up on AWS. Like I said I would like to save the credentials that the user inputs in the WebView (of my website) - save those on the device so that next time the user opens the app they are redirected to the home page of the WebView if the credentials are correct. Any suggestions on how I could achieve that?